# PHP retrieving post variable removes characters

Tags: php, post

My site is using the code

```
$_POST['products_previous_image'];
```

to retrieve product images and is returning `Photo 11-12-2015 2 23 05 PM.jpg`
when the post header contains:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="products_previous_image"

Photo 11-12-2015, 2 23 05 PM.jpg
```

This missing comma in the image path, is breaking the existing image when other fields are edited.

is there a way to fix this application side? or is this a server configuration isssue?

Comment: What missing comma?  What is `var_dump($_POST['products_previous_image'];);`?

Comment: And what does the form `input` look like?

Comment: in the image path, after 2015. There is a comma present in the request but when its extracted into a variable its gone. The output is: string(31) "Photo 11-12-2015 2 23 05 PM.jpg"

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="products_previous_image" value="Photo 11-12-2015, 2 23 05 PM.jpg">

Comment: Found the issue, a security patch was stripping all special characters from the headers. I might create an issue.

Comment: Good find.  If it is a common security software you might post it as an answer with detail (OS, webserver, software, patch etc...)